# Calculate Max Font size

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe

I'm tyring calculate the maximum fontsize in order for at Text to fit into the ClientRect of a TCxLabel. But I cant get it to work probably. (See picture)

[image]

The fontsize is to big and the thxt is not drawn the corrent place.

Here how to reproduce:

Place a tcxLabel on  an empty Form, and allign the label to client

Add a FormCreate and a FormResize event :

```
procedure TForm48.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CalculateNewFontSize;
end;

procedure TForm48.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CalculateNewFontSize;
end;
```

and Finally implement CalculateNewFontSize :

uses
  Math;

```
procedure TForm48.CalculateNewFontSize;
var
  ClientSize, TextSize: TSize;
begin

  ClientSize.cx := cxLabel1.Width;
  ClientSize.cy := cxLabel1.Height;

  cxLabel1.Style.Font.Size := 10;
  TextSize := cxLabel1.Canvas.TextExtent(Text);

  if TextSize.cx * TextSize.cx = 0 then
    exit;

  cxLabel1.Style.Font.Size := cxLabel1.Style.Font.Size * Trunc(Min(ClientSize.cx / TextSize.cx, ClientSize.cy / TextSize.cy) + 0.5);
end;
```

Does any one know how to calculate the font size and ho to place the text correctly?

Comment: `cxLabel1.Style.Font.Size := cxLabel1.Style.Font.Size * n` where `n` is an integer means you don't cover the font size space at all well.

Comment: Since Font.Size is an integer I need n to be an integer as well !?!

Comment: So if you start with a size of 12 then you believe that the next larger value is 24? Use MulDiv.

Comment: See also [How to autodraw the text based on graphiccontrols size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19731338/757830).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use something along these lines:

```
function LargestFontSizeToFitWidth(Canvas: TCanvas; Text: string; 
  Width: Integer): Integer;
var
  Font: TFont;
  FontRecall: TFontRecall;
  InitialTextWidth: Integer;
begin
  Font := Canvas.Font;
  FontRecall := TFontRecall.Create(Font);
  try
    InitialTextWidth := Canvas.TextWidth(Text);
    Font.Size := MulDiv(Font.Size, Width, InitialTextWidth);

    if InitialTextWidth < Width then
    begin
      while True do
      begin
        Font.Size := Font.Size + 1;
        if Canvas.TextWidth(Text) > Width then
        begin
          Result := Font.Size - 1;
          exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;

    if InitialTextWidth > Width then
    begin
      while True do
      begin
        Font.Size := Font.Size - 1;
        if Canvas.TextWidth(Text) <= Width then
        begin
          Result := Font.Size;
          exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FontRecall.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Make an initial estimate, and then fine tune by modifying the size by increments of one at a time. This is easy to understand and verify for correctness, and also quite efficient. In typical use the code will call `TextWidth` only a handful of times.

Comment: Thank your for your help David I've made my component based on your code nad I just want to share the  result with you and the rest of the world :D

http://pastebin.com/aK6nZNZk

Comment: @Kromster I think it must be a class that, on destruction, restores the original properties of the font passed into the constructor

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This code is very good but it doesn't work when scaling is not 100% (high-dpi monitor). How can we modify to make it work?

Comment: @Andrzej That doesn't sound right. Probably a misunderstanding at your end. Code shouldn't be affected by DPI.

Answer (score 3):

Text size doesn't depend linearly on font size. So you would better to increment or decrement font size by one and calculate text sizes, or find needed size with binary search (preferable, if size differs significantly)

Comment: Yes that was my first solution, but I perfered to to it in pure math

Comment: This problem is not solvable (for non-monospace fonts) with pure math, because size of different font elements (letters elements, intersymbol spaces etc) varies in a complicated manner. For example, ligature (example -connected ff) could exist for some font size and diappears for other size.